# Java GWT TreeViewModel SelectionHandler

Tags: java, gwt

In my project I need to fire an event after a node was clicked in my CellTree. I solved this with the following code.

```
model.setSelectionHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event)
    {
        //My logic is here
    }
});
```

The problem is that this only works if the node is not selected already. Clicking the node again will not fire the event. Is there a click handler or another event which is fired after a node was clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with SelectionHandler api .

Comment: Can you care to elaborate this a bit more? I already tried it with a SelectionHandler but this does not work if I click on a node multiple times only the first click is registered by the SelectionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating your own TreeItem that implements ClickHandler

```
public class CustomTreeItem extends TreeItem implements ClickHandler
{

    //classes logic here

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I use something like this:

```
model.setSelectionHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event)
    {
        SomeType selected = model.getSelectedObject();
        if (selected != null)
        {
            // Logic here...
            model.clear();
        }
    }
});
```

But this solution obviously removes visual feedback what was selected.

Comment: That's a nice idea but I cannot remove the visual feedback unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a DOM handler to your `CellTree` using [`Widget.addDomHandler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.html#addDomHandler(H, com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.Type)):

```
    cellTree.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            // TODO: check if a node is selected and it was clicked here
        }
    }, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Additionally you might need to prevent calling the handler twice if you use the selection handler as well and click a node.

*Just a side note: Unfortunately I did not see an easy way to determine if the user actually clicked on a tree item like a bounds check for the click coordinates. So this might get a bit harder to achieve.*